# What does request.form.get('field1') return when field1 is not filled out?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, post

I am trying to get data from a post method in HTML, but some of the fields are not required and can be left blank. If the user leaves the field blank, I want to make that value None.

example:

```
required_field = request.form.get("required_field")
not_required_field = request.form.get("not_required_field")
if (not_required_field is not set or was left blank):
     not_required_field = None
```

In PHP I would do something like this:

```
if (empty($_POST['field1'])) {$field1 = null;}
    else {$field1 = $_POST['field1'];}
```

but I cant figure out how to do this in Python.

I have also tried `request.args.get("field1")` which is None when the field is not set, also seems to be None when the user **does** fill in that field on the form.

How can I check if a form field has been left blank using `request.args.get()` or any other method? What does request.form.get() return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much any `.get()` method in Python will return `None` by default if the requested key was not found.

```
# get the submitted value (if any)
field = request.form.get("field")

# if a value was submitted, trim off leading/trailing blanks
if field:
    field = field.strip()

# if no value was submitted at all, or if the value was all blanks, default to None
if not field:
    field = None
```